# php--glob for searching directories and .jpg only

Tags: php, file, glob

What if I want to search for a only subdirectories AND certain file types.
Ex. I have a folder named “stuff” where random stuff is uploaded. And say I want to search for just subfolders AND .jpg files within “stuff” and nothing more. I know to search for only .jpg is…

`$array = glob(‘stuff/{*.jpg}’, GLOB_BRACE);`

and to search for only subdirectories is…

`$array = glob(‘stuff/*’, GLOB_ONLYDIR);`

…but how do I combine the two without getting any other unwanted files? Is there a pattern for subirectories for GLOB_BRACE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This recursive function should do the trick:

```
function recursiveGlob($dir, $ext) {
    $globFiles = glob("$dir/*.$ext");
    $globDirs  = glob("$dir/*", GLOB_ONLYDIR);

    foreach ($globDirs as $dir) {
        recursiveGlob($dir, $ext);
    }

    foreach ($globFiles as $file) {
        print "$file\n"; // Replace '\n' with '<br />' if outputting to browser
    }
}
```

Usage: `recursiveGlob('C:\Some\Dir', 'jpg');`

If you want it to do other things to the individual file, just replace the `print "$file\n"` part.

The function can be more specific in its `glob` searches and only match directories as well as files with the specified file extension, but I made it this way for simplicity and transparency.

Comment: I went back and tested the function and found it was not working. I corrected errors and optimised it. I hope you get this notice :-)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I am following exactly because with one you are looking for a specific file type, and with the other you are looking for subdirectories. Those are completely different patterns!

That being said, a way to have an array containing all *.jpg files in `stuff/` and also subdirectories in `stuff/` would be to take your code a step further:

```
$jpg_array = glob('stuff/{*.jpg}', GLOB_BRACE);
$subdir_array = glob('stuff/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR);

// Combine arrays
$items = array_merge($jpg_array,$subdir_array);

// Do something with values
foreach($items as $item)
{ 
   echo($item . "<br>");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Simple and clever.